# Display tasks in GNOME Shell Calendar

Tags: gnome3

Is it possible to make my Evolution tasks show up in the GNOME Shell Calendar?

When I pull down the calendar by clicking on the clock at the top of the screen (I'm using Fedora 20), it shows me the items I have entered into the calendar in Evolution. But it doesn't show me the tasks I have in Evolution. For example, I have a task scheduled as due on 7 March. But when I click on 7 March in the GNOME Shell Calendar, it shows up with nothing scheduled. Is it possible to have the tasks displayed as well?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible by using the extension [Task Widget](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3569/task-widget/)

Answer (score 0):

For tasks to show up on your calendar in the notification you can sync your email account using the `Online Accounts` option on the `gnome-control-center` and select what you would like to sync (eg. email, notes, tasks, etc.).

Or you can use the `gnome-calendar` application and input the tasks there, the notification calendar shows the appointments from the calendar.